# React caching my API requests

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am having this strange issue where React seems to be caching my API GET requests after I update an course. Just started learning React recently, so lots of new stuff to learn :)

Process:

First, I go to courseList.js, which lists all the courses. Then, I go to courseUpdate.js, which updates a specific course and redirects back to courseList.js

However, after I update a course, I am redirected back to courseList.js  and it outputs old data (prior to my update). I check my API server and see that my React app did not send any requests after the PATCH (update). In my console, I also see that the data is stale, but the timestamp is current. This issue is only occurring when I use

```
this.props.router.push('/courses');
or
browserHistory.push({pathname: '/courses'});
```

When I use

```
window.location.href = '/courses';
```

courseList.js loads fresh data as expected.

Any assistance or insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

courseList.js file:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        courses: [],
        loading: true
    };

    console.log("Current token: "+sessionStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    console.log("Expires: "+sessionStorage.getItem('access_token_expires'));
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetchCourses()
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState(state => {
                console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
                console.log(data);
                if(data["error"] === "invalid_grant"){
                    console.log("token expired...redirecting to login");
                    //TODO try to get new token without user redirect
                    this.props.router.push('/login');
                }else{
                    state.courses = data;
                    state.loading = false;
                    return state;
                }

            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('err', err);
        });
}

render() {
    let loading = this.state.loading ? 'loading' : 'loaded';
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Course list</h1>

            <table className={"table table-hover table-responsive text-center " +loading}>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="text-center">id</th>
                    <th className="text-center">Department</th>
                    <th className="text-center">Course Number</th>
                    <th className="text-center">Edit</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.courses && this.state.courses.map((post, i ) => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={post.id}>
                            <td>{post.id}</td>
                            <td>{post.department}</td>
                            <td>{post.course_number}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link to={`/courses/${post.id}`} className="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</Link>
                                <btn onClick={this.deleteHandler.bind(this, post.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</btn>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Link to={`/courses/create`} className="btn btn-default btn-sm">Create course</Link>
            <br/>
            <small>Page generated on: {new Date().toLocaleString()}</small>
        </div>
    );
}
```

courseUpdate.js

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
      courses: {}
    };
},

componentDidMount() {
    fetchCourse(this.props.params.courseId)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState(state => {
          console.log(data)
          if(data["error"] === "invalid_grant"){
            console.log("token expired...redirecting to login");
            //TODO try to get new token without user redirect
            this.props.router.push('/login');
          }else{
            state.courses = data;
            return state;
          }

        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('err', err);
      });

    },
    handleSubmit(data) {
        updateCourse(this.state.courses.id, data);

        //TODO figure out why window.location redirect works, but router and browserhistory does not
        //this.props.router.push('/courses');
        window.location.href = '/courses';
        /*
        browserHistory.push({
            pathname: '/courses'
        });
        */
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CourseForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    course_number={this.state.courses.course_number}
                    department={this.state.courses.department}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

API Calls:

```
export function fetchCourses() {
    console.log("Fetching courses");
    return fetch(Config.apiBaseUrl+'/courses', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.getToken(),
        },
        cache: 'no-cache'
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => err);
}

export function updateCourse(id, data){
    return fetch(Config.apiBaseUrl+'/courses/'+id, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.getToken(),
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => err);
}
```

Comment: Is `CourseList` and `CourseUpdate` displayed simultaneously (i.e. in a master-detail layout?) If so, `componentDidMount` wouldn't be called again when you navigate "away from" (react router Link does not cause a navigation event in browser) `courseUpdate`

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, it looks like you're using (component) local state where you should be using app state.

`this.setState(...)` in `courseUpdate` won't update the corresponding course in `courseList`. This is relevant for singlepage apps, especially when components aren't unloaded during navigation (such as, for example, what I mentioned in my comment above).

There are two ways to do this:

1 - [Lifting state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common parent. This is probably the easiest way to solve this issue. An example would be:

```
class ContainerComponent {
    updateItem = (item, newData) => {
        updateTheItem(item, newData).then((updatedItem) => {
            /* replace the item in state with updatedItem */
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetchItems().then(/* store items in state */);
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <List items={ items } onItemSelect={(item) => this.setState({ selectedItem: item })}>
                <Detail item={ this.state.selectedItem } updateItem={ this.updateItem }>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

within detail, instead of updating the item there, you'd call `props.updateItem`, which would update it in the parent, and sync the two children (both `List` and `Details`).

2 - I think you're looking for something like `redux` (and perhaps with `react-redux` bindings). State would be managed by a single store and components would read from it consistently. If it's going to be a large application, I would suggest going down this route - managing shared state between many different components can get hairy if you don't have help.